# How to make a rails form_for submit button a bootstrap button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make my rails `form_for` submit button look like the bootstrap `btn btn-lg btn-primary` button. I've tried a few different ways and have found no success. The best I could get is getting the `form_for` submit button in the center of a bootstrap button with different colors. Does anyone know what the command would be to get the bootstrap button to perform the action that my `f.submit` button does.

```
 <div class="Action">
     <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
= f.submit :Submit, class: 'btn btn-success'
```

Comment: I get the error `undefined local variable or method 'f'`

Comment: @Whitecat `f` is the form object, in a rails scaffold it's `form` e.g. `form.submit`

Answer (score 10):

By default `<%= f.submit %>` will create an `<input>` element according to the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#a-generic-search-form).

If you want to make it an actual `<button></button>` element, you can do it like this:

`<%= f.button "My Button", type: "submit", :class=> "btn btn-primary" %>`

Answer (score 2):

Not clear from the docs: if you still want the form_for to set the button name to '`Update <class>`' or '`Create <class>`' then pass `nil` into the submit:

```
<%= form.submit nil, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
= f.submit :Submit, class: 'btn btn-success'
```

or

```
= f.submit :Submit, class: :btn, class: :btn-success
```

Anyone getting errors on:

```
undefined local variable or method 'f'
```

Check what your form variable name is.
It will appear when you're declaring a form such as:

```
form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
```

Comment: other likely cause for `undefined local variable or method 'f'` is that maybe you are using `f.submit` ouside the scope of the `form_for` block, where `f` is available.